# How to deploy aws EventBridge with CDK - Python example

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I need some aws EventBridge CDK deployment- Python example ?

Did anyone has some code ?

Answer (score 18):

The following example is a well working Python CDK code.

The example demonstrates how to deploy an AWS EventBridge that simultaneously triggers a Step Function and a Lambda Function using AWS CDK (Cloud Deployment Kit).

by yl.

Pre-requisite:

- Python 3.7
- AWS CDK

Steps:

1) Deploys a lambda function

2) Prepares resources: EventBus, EventPattern (an EventBridge filter will be explained later on)

3) Creates a Step functions StateMachine

4) Creates rule using resources: EventBus, EventPattern, Targets: Lambda and State-Machine

```
from aws_cdk import aws_events as events
from aws_cdk import aws_events_targets as targets
from aws_cdk import (
    aws_lambda as _lambda,
    aws_stepfunctions as sfn,
    aws_stepfunctions_tasks as sfn_tasks
)
from aws_cdk import core
import typing

class CdkEventBridgeStack(core.Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: core.Construct, id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, id, **kwargs)

        # 1) deploy lambda function
        base_lambda = CdkEventBridgeStack.lambdaDeploy(self)

        # 2) prepare resources EventBus, EventPattern, Rule-Target
        eventBus, eventPattern, lambdaTarget1 = CdkEventBridgeStack.creEventBusAndEventPatternAndLambdaTarget(self, base_lambda)

        # 3) create step functions StateMachine
        stateMachineTarget = CdkEventBridgeStack.createStateMachine(self, base_lambda)

        # 4) create rule using resources: EventBus, EventPattern, Rule-Targets: Lambda and State-Machine
        CdkEventBridgeStack.createRule(self, [lambdaTarget1, stateMachineTarget], eventBus, eventPattern)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def lambdaDeploy(this) -> None:
        base_lambda = _lambda.Function(this, 'MyLambda',
                                       function_name='MyLambda1',
                                       handler='testTargtetLambda.lambda_handler',
                                       runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                                       code=_lambda.Code.asset('cdk_event_bridge/functions'),
                                       )
        return base_lambda
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def creEventBusAndEventPatternAndLambdaTarget(this, base_lambda: _lambda.IFunction):
        eventBus      = events.EventBus(scope=this, id="orders1", event_bus_name="orders2")
        eventPattern  = events.EventPattern(source=['XXX'])
        lambdaTarget1 = targets.LambdaFunction(handler=base_lambda)

        return eventBus, eventPattern, lambdaTarget1
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def createRule(this, targetsList : typing.Optional[typing.List["IRuleTarget"]] = None, eventBus: typing.Optional["IEventBus"]=None, eventPattern: typing.Optional["EventPattern"]=None):
        events.Rule(scope=this,
                    id="x123",
                    rule_name="routeToLambda",
                    targets=targetsList,
                    description="cdk Test Rule navigates to Lambda",
                    event_bus=eventBus,
                    event_pattern=eventPattern,
                    )
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @staticmethod
    def createStateMachine(this, lambda_function: _lambda.IFunction):
        submit_job_activity = sfn.Activity(
            this, "SubmitJob"
        )
        check_job_activity = sfn.Activity(
            this, "CheckJob"
        )

        submit_job = sfn.Task(
            this, "Submit Job",
            # task=sfn_tasks.InvokeActivity(submit_job_activity),
            task=sfn_tasks.InvokeFunction(lambda_function),
            result_path="$.guid",
        )

        get_status = sfn.Task(
            this, "Get Job Status",
            # task=sfn_tasks.InvokeActivity(check_job_activity),
            task=sfn_tasks.InvokeFunction(lambda_function),
            input_path="$.guid",
            result_path="$.status",
        )

        finalStatus =  sfn.Succeed(
            this, 'Final Job Status'
        )

        # definition = submit_job.next(get_status).end_states(sfn.Succeed())
        definition = submit_job\
                     .next(get_status) ##.next(finalStatus)

        machineHandler = sfn.StateMachine(
            this, "StateMachine222",
            definition=definition,
            state_machine_name="CdkTestStateMachine",
            timeout=core.Duration.seconds(30),
        )
        #  machine: aws_cdk.aws_stepfunctions.IStateMachine
        stateMachineTarget = targets.SfnStateMachine(machine=machineHandler)
        return  stateMachineTarget

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note:

```
code=_lambda.Code.asset('cdk_event_bridge/functions'),
```

on the Lambda function deployment

```
base_lambda = _lambda.Function(this, 'MyLambda',
                               function_name='MyLambda1',
                               handler='testTargtetLambda.lambda_handler',
                               runtime=_lambda.Runtime.PYTHON_3_7,
                               code=_lambda.Code.asset('cdk_event_bridge/functions'),
                               )
```

The _lambda.Code.asset points to the 'functions' folder where the lambda code is located
when the folder hierarchy is:

```
/cdk_event_bridge+
                 +-cdk_event_bridge_stack.py  <= this cdk deployment script
                 +-/functions/+    <= a folder
                              +-testTargtetLambda.py  <= Lambda code
```